# Reading a double stored in a binary format in a character array

Tags: c++, floating-point, binary

I am trying to read a floating point number stored as a specific binary format in a char array. The format is as follows, where each letter represents a binary digit:

```
SEEEEEEE MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM
```

The format is more clearly explained in this [website](http://boolean.klaasholwerda.nl/interface/bnf/gdsformat.html). Basically, the exponent is in Excess-64 notation and the mantissa is normalized to values <1 and >1/16. To get the true value of the number the mantissa is multipled by 16 to the power of the true value of the exponent.

Basicly, what I've done so far is to extract the sign and the exponent values, but I'm having trouble extracting the mantissa. The implementation I'm trying is quite brute force and is probably far from ideal in terms of code but it seemed to me as the simplest. It basicly is:

```
unsigned long a = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    a += static_cast<unsigned long>(m_bufRecord[index+1+i])<<((6-i)*8);
```

It takes every 8-bit byte size stored in the char array and shifts it left according to its index in the array. So if the array I have is as follows:

```
{0x3f, 0x28, 0xf5, 0xc2, 0x8f, 0x5c, 0x28, 0xf6}
```

I'm expecting `a` to take the value:

```
0x28f5c28f5c28f6
```

However, with the above implementation `a` takes the value:

```
0x27f4c18f5c27f6
```

Later, I convert the long integer to a floating number using the following code:

```
double m = a;

m = m*(pow(16, e-14));
m = (s==1)?-m:m;
```

What is going wrong here? Also, I'd love to know how a conversion like this would be implemented ideally?

Comment: This is like the tenth question in the last two days about the exact same thing. Is it some kind of homework deadline? Does your prof know that you're asking for an answer on SO about this?

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I haven't seen the previous questions, though I did a search if anything similar was asked before. The context of this, if you must know, is about reading a GDSII format file (a file format to store IC layouts primarily.) More information here: (http://boolean.klaasholwerda.nl/interface/bnf/gdsformat.html) Also, no professors are involved whatsoever.

Comment: Fair enough, and apologies for the insinuation.

Comment: Does a `long` actually have enough size for 56 bits? In any event you could write the binary representation of an IEE754 `double` directly without the intermediate step.

Comment: Is the format actually matching a 64-bit? Isn't the exponent more than 8 bits in a `double`?

Comment: In my platfrom `sizeof(long)` gives 8, so I was guessing I was safe for up to 64 bits. However, I'm pretty sure this could be problematic if I went to a 32-bit architecture. So the problem about __why__ this doesnt work still remains a mystery to me.

I also think writing binary directly into the double format would be the ideal solution, but I have no idea how to get started with coding that.

Comment: The question is ambiguous because it does not say whether or not the mantissa is always normalized, whether there's an implicit 1 (as in IEE754) in it, whether it's 2's complement or sign-magnitude, etc. Before the question can be answered, the format must be defined. At the very least, there must be enough examples provided to deduce the format from them.

Comment: I thought the existence of a sign bit implied that it's sign-magnitude. The format is more clearly explained at the link I gave in an above comment, and it states __"The mantissa is always a positive fraction >=1/16 and <1. For a 4-byte real, the mantissa is bits 8-31. For an 8-byte real, the mantissa is bits 8-63."__ so it is normalized. However, my question is not quite about the interpretation about the format, but more so about the problem I'm encountering while reading the mantissa bytes into a unsigned long integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried running your code, but I suspect the reason you get this:

```
0x27f4c18f5c27f6
```

instead of

```
0x28f5c28f5c28f6
```

is because your have a "negative number" in the cell previous to it. Are your 8-bit byte array a signed or unsigned value? I expect it will work better if you make it unsigned. [Or move your cast so that it's before the shift operations].

Comment: My byte array is a char* so it is signed, but I think I'm doing the casting before the the shift operation. Is the above code not doing that?

Comment: I would print the intermediate values before "adding" [I personally would use `|` to or in the the values, as that saves any unwanted "borrowing" if adding negative values, etc].

Comment: This certainly seems to be the problem, `static_cast<unsigned long>(0xf3)` (0xf3 is actually a value stored in a char* array) results in `0xfffffffffffffff3` which is certainly not what I want. Correcting the expression to `static_cast<unsigned long>(0xf3)&0xff` seems to solve the problem but what I don't understand is if this is intended behavior?

Comment: I think what happens is that it's extended to long first, then converted to unsigned, which is the opposite of what you need. I have had similar problems in the past, and had to either do double casts or use `unsigned` in the first place [which probably would solve the problem in your case too].

Comment: Makes sense. Using `static_cast<unsigned>()` doesn't work for my case due to the size of the default int. I'll either have to use a double cast or the `static_cast<unsigned long>()&0xff`. I think I'll favor the double cast due to its better readability.